# Elasticsearch Nest doesn't insert document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, nest

I have two **POCO types**
 PdfIndex and PieceEM:

```
 public class PdfIndex
 {
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public PieceEM Pdf { get; set; }
 }
```

And PieceEM:

```
public class PieceEM
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
    public string DeparmentOfPiece { get; set; }
    public string PieceType { get; set; }
    public string PricingType { get; set; }
    public string PieceId { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

All pdfs read and but not indexed.
The code does not fail, just this address has no data
http://localhost:9200/fullegalpieces/_search?pretty=true

This is my index code:

```
public void IndexPiece(IEnumerable<PdfIndex> pdfIndexes)
    {
        foreach (var pdfIndex in pdfIndexes)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(pdfIndex.Path)) continue;

            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfIndex.Path);
            string text = string.Empty;
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page);
            }
            pdfReader.Close();

            PieceEM _pdf = pdfIndex.Pdf;
            _pdf.Content = IndexDocumentHelper.RemoveSpecialChar(text);
            _pdf.Content += _pdf.Author;

            _elasticClient.Index(_pdf, i => i
            .Type<PieceEM>());
        }
    }
```

Path is correct.
This pdf exists locally,
and my post action is here:

```
     [HttpPost]
    public void IndexPiece(List<PdfIndex> pdfIndexes)
    {
        var elastic = new ElasticHelper.ElasticSearchHelper("http://localhost:9200/", "fullegalpieces");
        elastic.IndexPiece(new List<PdfIndex> {
            new PdfIndex
            {
                Path = @"C:\Users\Yılmaz\Desktop\özgeçmiş.pdf",
                Pdf = new PieceEM
                {
                    Id = "042f01f8-befc-40a7-9339-fa4fffe2c4e0",
                    PieceId = "bd7aaa9c-7c81-4675-a037-0fa56ad09003",
                    Language = "1",
                    PieceType ="2",
                    PricingType = "1",
                    Profession = "1",
                    Author = "ykaraagac",
                    DeparmentOfPiece = "1"
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

I have similar examples, but this does not work.
What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you join response of elastic when you try to index 1 document? Is the index empty or already exist, in this case, join the mapping. Have you any error on elastic logs file?

Comment: my index like is here:

    {
      took: 35,
      timed_out: false,
        _shards: {
       total: 5,
         successful: 5,
      skipped: 0,
     failed: 0
         },
            hits: {
             total: 0,
          max_score: null,
           hits: [ ]
       }
}

Comment: how to see elasticsearch log file?

Comment: In your elasticsearch serveur (or folder if he is on localhost), in /logs, check the exception. Your index doesnot have existing mapping yet?

Comment: `     public void CreatePieceIndex(string name)
        {
            var createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(name)
                                   .Mappings(ms => ms.Map<PieceEM>(m => m.AutoMap()));
            var response = _elasticClient.CreateIndex(createIndexDescriptor);
        } `

@LeBigCat this method is run

Comment: @LeBigCat my log file: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/184YGbdXQspgJWpNBf0dkX1bQlZrH-GE1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: seems you got mapping issus (Rejecting mapping update to [fullegalpieces]) please extract mapping for es, if you modified PdfIndex class this is the issue. Also delete index if possible, and callback your CreatePieceIndex function.

Comment: You should check the response returned from indexing: `_elasticClient.Index(_pdf, i => i.Type<PieceEM>());`. By default, the client does not throw exceptions from operations, and instead you should check the `.IsValid` property on the response. You can change this behaviour on `ConnectionSettings` by calling `.ThrowExceptions()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked my local log file and i saw this:

i indexed different POCO type, not PieceEM